# How to upload a PDF file and send via email in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I'm Having a form with the following fields.

- Name
- Address
- Contact
- PDF (File Attachment)

This PDF is to be uploaded from the system and send these details together with the uploaded PDF via email. I want these details to be in the custom email template using standalone view and send.

I'm using TYPO3 v7.6.23

I'm new to TYPO3. How to do This?

**I'm adding my code here**

```
$addJobsInfo = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('MNU\\MnuJobs\\Domain\\Model\\Jobs'); 
$addJobsInfo->setName($arguments['name']);
$addJobsInfo->setAddress($arguments['address']);
$addJobsInfo->setContact($arguments['contact']);             
$this->jobsRepository->add($addJobsInfo);
$persistenceManager = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager');
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
$lastID = $addJobsInfo->getUid();            

$getPDF = $_FILES;                        
if(!empty($getPDF)){
    $pdfName = $getPDF['tx_mnujobs_mnujobs']['name']['jobsDOC'];  
    $pdfTemp = $getPDF['tx_mnujobs_mnujobs']['tmp_name']['jobsDOC'];   
    $resourceFactory = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance();
    $storage = $resourceFactory->getDefaultStorage();
    $folder = $storage->getFolder('user_upload');
    $pdfFinalName = 'Jobs_'.time().'_'.$pdfName;
    $uploadPDF = $storage->addFile($pdfTemp, $folder, $pdfFinalName);            

    if($lastID){
        $newId = 'NEW'.$lastID;
        $data = array();
        $data['sys_file_reference'][$newId] = array(
            'table_local' => 'sys_file',
            'uid_local' => $uploadPDF->getUid(),
            'tablenames' => 'tx_mnujobs_domain_model_jobs',
            'uid_foreign' => $lastID,
            'fieldname' => 'pdfattachment',
            'pid' => $this->settings['pageUid']
        );
        $dataHandler = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataHandler::class);
        $dataHandler->start($data, array());
        $dataHandler->process_datamap();                
    }
}    

//E-mail Sending
$mail = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
$mail->setSubject('Contact Details');
$mail->setTo('sample@gmail.com']);
$mail->setBody('Hi, This is a sample. Please Find the Attachment', 'text/html');
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($folder->getIdentifier().$pdfFinalName);
$attachment->setFilename('Document.pdf');
$mail->attach($attachment);
$sendMail = $mail->send();
```

I'm getting this Exception

> Unable to open file for reading
>   [/user_upload/Jobs_1525757243_sample.pdf]

So I've replaced this

```
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($folder->getIdentifier().$pdfFinalName, 'Document.pdf', 'application/pdf');
$mail->attach($attachment);
```

Both are not working, Where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was adding `fileadmin` in front of the identifier:

```
$filePath = 'fileadmin' . $file->getOriginalResource()->getIdentifier();
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($filePath);
$mail->attach($attachment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ext:powermail, it is feature rich, actively maintained and very well documented

Comment: Thank you, But I need to create a custom extension. using swift mailer. I have created and inserted the data but I'm fed up of with the Swift mailer attachment. (i've included the code)

Comment: I probably can't help you there. But first check if the file is there and if so, it has the right permissions. Just a note about powermail: I use it in combination with a custom extension, writing to the database with finisher classes.